# How to mock a function using Jest that has parameters in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ts-jest

I have a method `add` which I want to mock:

A.js

```
function add(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c
}

export add;
```

I am calling this `add` method in `componentDidMount` like this

B.js

```
import add from './A';

class AddForm extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
       add(1, 2, 3);
    }
    ...
}

export AddForm;
```

Now this is how I am testing it

B.test.js

```
import AddForm from './B';

const helpers = require("./A");
jest.spyOn(helpers, "add").mockImplementation(() => 100);

describe('<AddForm/>', () => {
  test('should render all elements', () => {
     return render(
      <AddForm></AddForm>,
     );
  }
}
```

I am not getting the mocked value `100` while testing instead the function is getting executed. I tried all answers that are available but unable to get this mocked response.

Anything that I am missing here?

Comment: Just mocked the whole module should help

Comment: Can you share me a snippet on that @TonyYip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these documents

- https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules
- https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api

Sample:

```js
const helpers = require("./A");
jest.mock('./A')
test('should render all elements', () => {
  helper.add.mockReturnValue(100);
  // write your test case
});
```